# Android Trouble getting info returned from Url using InputStreamReader

Tags: java, android, url

I am sending info to a php file through a url. When I type the url in my browser the right information is displayed, however I do not get this information through the InputStreamReader.

Here is my code.

```
 try {
          URL url = new URL("http://example/example.php?userImage="
         + URLEncoder.encode(userImageString, "UTF-8") + "&userHeight="
         + URLEncoder.encode(userHeight,"UTF-8" ));
          Log.d("url", "" + url);
          Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))
            .useDelimiter("\n");

          Log.d("hasnext?", "" + in.hasNext());
      while (in.hasNext()) 
      {
          Log.d("sent", in.next());
      }
      in.close();
    }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

HasNext returns false, it should be returning true. Any suggestions?

I should note that the userImageString is a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: Try replacing `Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))
            .useDelimiter("\n");` with `Scanner in = new Scanner(url.openStream());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do you have the permission to access the internet?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2) I think you can solve your problem with this answere:
[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android)

3) Here is a working http request which returns the response:

```
public String request(String fUrl){
    String page = "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(fUrl);
        HttpResponse response = hc.execute(post);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            page = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception Thrown");
    }
    return page;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have an internet connection, I have done similar url calls on different parts off my application, which is why I cannot understand why this one is only working using a browser.

Comment: Using a HttpClient object is a lot easier, so I recommend using that instead of a InputStreamReader.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to work with them before, is there a simple way to read from the results of a HTTPClient?

Comment: I have added a working http request function in point 3 of my answere